# Remove an opencv contour from a list of contours

Tags: python, list, opencv, python-itertools, contour

With `opencv`, I'm detecting contours and selecting some of them:

```
CNTS = []
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for c in contours:
    if some_condition(c):
        CNTS.append(c)
```

Then I'm looping over 2-subsets {c1, c2} of the list of contours, and removing some of them:

```
TMP = CNTS[:]  # copy it, to avoid deleting element from a list while looping on it!
for c1, c2 in itertools.combinations(TMP, 2):
    if dist(c1, c2) < 100  # custom function to evaluate distance between 2 contours
        if c1 in CNTS:  # it might have been already removed
            CNTS.remove(c1)
```

Here comes the problem in the `CNTS.remove(c1)` line:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

**How to correctly remove a contour from a list of `opencv` contours?**

Note: in fact, it works most of the time, but sometimes, after a few iterations, I have this bug. Maybe because a contour is a list of points, and then **testing if a "list of points" is member of another list** is ambiguous?

More generally, in Python, are there some ambiguous cases when testing if a list of points (=list of lists of 2 elements!) is itself a member of another list?

Comment: Contour is a list of point (or a np.ndarray), you should define your custom dist function. But you havn't show it.

Comment: @Silencer I fixed a wrong copy/paste in the question. The problem is in the `.remove(c1)` line. It's like testing if `c1` (a list of points or np.ndarray) is member of a list `CNTS` is problematic.

Comment: Try to iterator them by index, the save then results into a new contours.

Comment: You are making a copy of the list already, so are you interested in an answer that simply filters contours and creates a new list, rather than using `CNTS.remove()`? I tested using `.remove()` on a list of contours and it seemed to work fine by the way.

Comment: @Silencer: that's what I finally do: I keep a list of contour *indexes*, and do the removing in the list of *integers*. This works, of course, but usually with Python it's possible to avoid such things (that I would do all the time in C!) and work with list of objects instead of list of indexes.

Comment: @W.Dodge For me, it works most of the time, but sometimes, I have this bug. Maybe because a contour is a list of points, and then **testing if a "list of points" is member of a list** is ambiguous? More generally in Python, are there some ambiguous cases when testing if a list of points (=list of lists of 2 elements!) is itself a member of another list?

Answer (score 0):

You already removed it. The error raised because you try to remove it TWICE.

Try this:

```
popup = []
for i in range(len(CNTS)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(CNTS)):
        if dist(CNTS[i], CNTS[j]) < 100:
            popup.append(i)
            break
for i in popup[::-1]:
    CNTS.pop(i)
```

Comment: Thank you. In fact, in my code, I already checked if it has already been removed or not (check updated question).