# Test if a numpy array is a member of a list of numpy arrays, and remove it from the list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

When testing if a numpy array `c` is member of a list of numpy arrays `CNTS`:

```
import numpy as np

c = np.array([[[ 75, 763]],
              [[ 57, 763]],
              [[ 57, 749]],
              [[ 75, 749]]])

CNTS = [np.array([[[  78, 1202]],
                  [[  63, 1202]],
                  [[  63, 1187]],
                  [[  78, 1187]]]),
        np.array([[[ 75, 763]],
                  [[ 57, 763]],
                  [[ 57, 749]],
                  [[ 75, 749]]]),
        np.array([[[ 72, 742]],
                  [[ 58, 742]],
                  [[ 57, 741]],
                  [[ 57, 727]],
                  [[ 58, 726]],
                  [[ 72, 726]]]),
        np.array([[[ 66, 194]],
                  [[ 51, 194]],
                  [[ 51, 179]],
                  [[ 66, 179]]])]

print(c in CNTS)
```

I get:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

However, the answer is rather clear: `c` is exactly `CNTS[1]`, so `c in CNTS` should return True!

**How to correctly test if a numpy array is member of a list of numpy arrays?**

The same problem happens **when removing**:

```
CNTS.remove(c)
```

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Application: test if an `opencv` contour (numpy array) is member of a list of contours, see for example [Remove an opencv contour from a list of contours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53051275/remove-an-opencv-contour-from-a-list-of-contours).

Comment: @DavidG the real problem (for the [application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53051275/remove-an-opencv-contour-from-a-list-of-contours)) is not only test membership, but also remove a numpy array from a list of numpy arrays, I added more details to the question. It's not really a duplicate.

Comment: I think you can use `bool(sum((map(lambda x: np.array_equal(x,c), CNTS))))`

Comment: @RudolfMorkovskyi. You could just use `any`, which would also do short-circuiting

Comment: Are all the arrays going to be the same size?

Comment: @MadPhysicist No, those arrays are *contours*, i.e. list of points, it can be a rectangle (4 points), pentagon (5 points), etc.

Comment: @MadPhysicist year, really this is better solution

Comment: @Basj. I hope you don't mind my edit. I made it a bit more clear that the arrays are not all the same size.

Comment: @MadPhysicist it's perfect!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting the error because `in` essentially invokes `bool(c == x)` on every element `x` of `CNTS`. It's the `__bool__` conversion that is raising the error:

```
>>> c == CNTS[1]
array([[[ True,  True]],
       [[ True,  True]],
       [[ True,  True]],
       [[ True,  True]]])

>>> bool(_)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

The same applies for removal, since it tests for equality with each element.

**Containment**

The solution is to use `np.array_equal` or apply the `all` method to each comparison:

```
any(np.array_equal(c, x) for x in CNTS)
```

OR

```
any((c == x).all() for x in CNTS)
```

**Removal**

To perform the removal, you are more interested in the index of the element than its existence. The fastest way I can think of is to iterate over the indices, using the elements of `CNTS` as comparison keys:

```
index = next((i for i, x in enumerate(CNTS) if (c == x).all()), -1)
```

This option short circuits quite nicely, and returns `-1` as the default index rather than raising a `StopIteration`. You can remove the argument `-1` to `next` if you prefer the error. If you prefer, you can replace `(c == x).all()` with `np.array_equal(c, x)`.

Now you can remove as usual:

```
del CNTS[index]
```

Comment: Thank you @MadPhysicist. As I mentioned in the edited question, the goal is to test membership to finally remove it (if present in the list of numpy arrays). How would you do the latter?

Comment: @Basj. Updated to include removal

Comment: Weird indeed (I upvoted all the 3 answers) @MadPhysicist!

Answer (score 3):

This solution could work for this case:

```
def arrayisin(array, list_of_arrays):
    for a in list_of_arrays:
        if np.array_equal(array, a):
            return True
    return False
```

This function iterates over a list of arrays and tests the equality against some other array. So the usage would be:

```
>>> arrayisin(c, CNTS)
True
```

To remove the array from the list, you can get the index of the array and then use `list.pop`. In the function `get_index`, we enumerate the list of arrays, meaning we zip the indices of the list and the contents of the list. If there is a match, we return the index of the match.

```
def get_index(array, list_of_arrays):
    for j, a in enumerate(list_of_arrays):
        if np.array_equal(array, a):
            return j
    return None

idx = get_index(c, CNTS)  # 1
CNTS.pop(idx)
```

Please see the python data structures tutorial for the documentation of `list.pop` https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: Thank you @Jakub. As I mentioned in the question, the goal is to test membership to finally remove it (if present in the list of numpy arrays). How would you do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use `del` to delete the index of the list you want to remove.

```
del CNTS[int(np.where(list(np.array_equal(row, c) for row in CNTS))[0])]

CNTS

[array([[[  78, 1202]],

        [[  63, 1202]],

        [[  63, 1187]],

        [[  78, 1187]]]), array([[[ 72, 742]],

        [[ 58, 742]],

        [[ 57, 741]],

        [[ 57, 727]],

        [[ 58, 726]],

        [[ 72, 726]]]), array([[[ 66, 194]],

        [[ 51, 194]],

        [[ 51, 179]],

        [[ 66, 179]]])]
```

Comment: This does not short circuit, and creates an extra numpy array, just to call np.where...

Comment: Thanks @MadPhysicist, answer modified

Comment: I tried running your updated code and it does not work as advertised. np.where will wrap any input in an array. Generators do not get expanded, so it gives you index 0 no matter what (since a generator object is truthy).

Comment: I would recommend going back to your original answer with `list`. While not optimal, it worked perfectly.

Comment: `int(np.where(list(np.array_equal(row, c) for row in CNTS))[0])` -> 1, `int(np.where((np.array_equal(row, c) for row in CNTS))[0])` -> 0. I'm using numpy 1.14.2. Perhaps in version 15, generators are expanded?

Comment: Yes, you are right, Thanks, Have not noticed, Thanks, @MadPhysicist